# Continuity of functionals in function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I came across this problem and got confused. With the help of folks at MathStackExchange I managed to understand the following:

Define $h:C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ by $$h(x)=\sup_{0\leq t\leq1}|x(t)|$$ $h$ is continuous in $C[0,1]$

I have some further problems..

**Problem:**

(1)what if we make $h$ something else.Are they all continuous?  like $$h(x)=\int_0^1x(t)dt$$ this one is a linear functional.. I think there is a theorem about linear functional that shows that it's continuous iff its bounded or it satisfies some other conditions.. I could not recall how many but perhaps 4 equivalent statements in that theorem..

(2) what if we make $$h(x)=\inf x(t)$$ or $$h(x)=\sup x(t)$$I don't think this time these two are norms..

(3) what if we make $$h(x)=x(1)$$ I think is is linear.. So will it suffice to show that it is bounded?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Note that if $(x_n)$ converges uniformly to $x$, then we can interchange limit and integration, so $h$ is continuous.

(2) Note that for any $x,y\in C[0,1]$ we find $a,b\in[0,1]$ such that $x(a)=\sup x$ and $y(b)=\sup y$. Moreover, $y(b)\geq y(a)$ and hence $\sup x-\sup y=x(a)-y(b)\leq x(a)-y(a)\leq\sup(x-y)\leq||x-y||_\infty$, and since this is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ we have $|\sup x-\sup y|\leq||x-y||_\infty$. In particular, if $h(x)=\sup x$, then $|h(x)-h(y)|\leq||x-y||_\infty$, so $h$ is continuous. The case $h(x)=\inf x$ is similar (you can also use $\inf x=-\sup(-x)$).

(3) If $(x_n)$ converges uniformly to $x$, then it converges pointwise, so $h(x_n)=x_n(1)\to x(1)=h(x)$. That shows that $h$ is again continuous.

Comment: I did get one downvote here. Dont know why :(

Comment: I probably clicked it by mistake...sry i have added it back!